# WalletConnect with Ethersjs

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, wallet-connect

is anyway to use walletconnect with etherejs ?

the demos are nice but they are with wagmi

i cant port all project from etherjs to wagmi

i need this feature this button connect disconect and possibility to use only few networks/chainids

```
import { arbitrum, mainnet, polygon } from "wagmi/chains";
```

[image]

https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/react/installation

i this this exactly but with ETHERSJS

```
const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [
  walletConnectProvider({ projectId: "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>" }),
]);
const wagmiClient = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: modalConnectors({ appName: "web3Modal", chains }),
  provider,
});

// Web3Modal Ethereum Client
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);
```

Comment: I ended up using wagmi + fetchSigner() then everything else directly on ethers. Still looking for an easier walletconnect 2.0 integration to ethers without wagmi.

Answer (score 1):

I found official example for WalletConnect v2 integration with Ethers.js

New 2024 solution (**Does not seems to be reliable):

**Official example https://github.com/WalletConnect/web-examples/blob/main/dapps/ethereum-provider/src/App.tsx#L25C49-L25C61**

- Note that using **Ethers v6** it's required to use `BrowserProvider` instead of `Web3Provider`

```
const provider = await EthereumProvider.init({ ...params });
const ethersProvider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(provider);
// Activate wallet - trigger modal
const signer = await ethersProvider.provider.getSigner();
const address = await signer.getAddress();
// Now you have acceess to provider - cache it until page reload
// + add Disconnect (see example)
```

Older/Until 2024 solution:

Previous example was here but most likely above is more up to date: https://github.com/WalletConnect/web-examples/blob/2.7.8/dapps/react-dapp-v2-with-ethers/src/contexts/ClientContext.tsx

- Bad thing is that it's more complex than one with `Wagmi`. You have to connect lot of WalletConnect events to keep session info up to date, or to reset connection state.
- Also official example (`ClientContext.tsx`) is IMO overusing React state which is not ideal. Would be nice to have official Ethers wrapper (not React, or other UI library dependent).
- But it is definitely useful example to make Ethers integration work.